# Why aren't Kynetx browser apps available on addons.mozilla.org or chrome.google.com/extensions?

Tags: krl

Is there any restriction on publishing Kynetx browser apps on addons.mozilla.org or chrome.google.com/extensions that explains why there are no kynetx apps available there ?

When I search for "Kynetx"  I get 0 results.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=kynetx&cat=all&x=0&y=0

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/search?itemlang=&hl=en&q=kynetx

0 results too when I search for PeerIndex, HoverMe, TwiKlout, YouTube Refreshed ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there are restrictions for Mozilla Firefox Add-ons. My submission of Hoverme was rejected because it performed remote JavaScript execution. Which is a fundamental part of the Kynetx Browser Application architecture. As stated on their [Review Process: Add-on Policies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/policies/reviews) page remote JavaScript execution is not allowed. But the good news is that we have the Kynetx [Browser Application Marketplace](http://apps.kynetx.com/)

Comment: Then maybe there should exist a "regular" FF extension on Mozilla Firefox Add-ons that allows us to install Kynetx browser apps from KBX.

Comment: I also believe there is a way to build Kynetx browser apps that are compatible with the restrictions you mention. kobj-static.js and the ruleset generated js code could be packaged inside the FF extension . All "emits" could be replaced with a json response like : [here](http://globalconstant.scnay.com/2011/04/09/creating-a-restful-web-service-with-krl/) and the FF extension would react to the json response. We'd lose "autoupdate" but that isn't allowed anyway by Mozilla. The Mozilla Firefox Add-on page gets so many visitors that I believe it is important to increase Kynetx presence there.

Comment: Since the [dual execution environment](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Dual_Execution_Environment) is a fundamental component of the Kynetx runtime architecture I do not believe it would be possible to generate standalone browser extensions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no technical reason why they can't be listed. That's on our radar and we're working on that. Expect to see it there soon.